# Watch won't show time

Tags: terraria

In Terraria, I have a watch in my hotbar. I always keep it there, but the last time I looked, it won't show the time anymore. Is this a glitch, or what's happening with the watch?

Comment: Do you have the inventory view open? Also, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'll check when I get home, but I don't think you need to have it on your hotbar for it to show you the time. Just having it in your inventory should be enough. The time should be displayed in the top right, just under the minimap as long as you don't have your inventory open and you haven't accidentally turned off the display.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you have the Watch in your inventory (it doesn't need to be on your hotbar, just having it with you is enough) you should be able to see the time displayed underneath your minimap in the top right of the screen:

[image: Image showing the info display underneath the minimap]

Do bear in mind though - the information will only display while your inventory **is closed**. You may also enable/disable individual info items by clicking their icon while the inventory is open:

[image: Image showing display with inventory open and time enabled]

In the above image everything is enabled, whereas below, time is disabled:

[image: Image showing display with inventory open and time disabled]

If you can't see the time, check that you haven't accidentally disabled it by looking at the icon. If it's disabled, simply click it to re-enable it.

Comment: Never knew that one could do this!

Comment: Your base looks amazing, from what I can see. Good work.

Answer (score 2):

The display of time can be toggled by clicking the watch icon underneath the minimap while an inventory is open. Maybe you accidentally clicked the watch icon.